# How to get .ts var value in *ngIf HTML?

Tags: html, angular, var

I am trying to display images all 2 seconds, I managed to display them all first.

Here is my HTML line :

```html
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngIf="bh?.id == count" [src]="bh?.src" height="42" width="42"/>
```

And my .ts method :

```
  Timer(){
  setInterval(() => {
    this.count=this.count++
  }, 2000)
}
```

with :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
count=0

BHs = [
  new Bh (1, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg.png"),
  new Bh (2, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH2.png"),
  new Bh (3, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH3.png"),
  new Bh (4, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH4.png"),
  new Bh (5, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH5.png"),
  new Bh (6, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH6.png"),
  new Bh (7, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH7.png"),
  new Bh (8, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH8.png"),
  new Bh (9, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH9.png"),
  new Bh (10, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH10.png"),
  new Bh (11, "assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH11.png"),
];
}
```

Btw it was displaying with *ngFor but I guess I have to use *ngIf here..

I also tried :

```html
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngIf="bh?.id == this.count" [src]="bh?.src" height="42" width="42"/>
```

but not working.. Thank you very much !

Comment: where is `bh` coming from?

Comment: `this.count` should be `count`, but changing won't help your problem i think.

Comment: oh sorry i'll add it

Comment: Ok thank you @TheNsn666, this is a first help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good for the most part, I adjusted some places. the only couple of more problems that it could be, is the wrong picture path, which probably should start with '/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg' and definitely shouldn't have two extensions.
And another would be that your Bh class constructor creates the class but you don't assign and expose the id properly.

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
count=0

BHs = [
  new Bh(1, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg"),
  new Bh(2, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH2.png"),
  new Bh(3, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH3.png"),
  new Bh(4, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH4.png"),
  new Bh(5, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH5.png"),
  new Bh(6, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH6.png"),
  new Bh(7, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH7.png"),
  new Bh(8, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH8.png"),
  new Bh(9, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH9.png"),
  new Bh(10, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH10.png"),
  new Bh (11, "/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH11.png"),
];
}
ngOnInit() {
 Timer(){
  setInterval(() => {
    this.count++
  }, 2000)
 }
}

--------------------HTML----------------
<ng-container *ngFor="let bh of BHs">
  <img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngIf="bh.id === count" [src]="bh.src" height="42" 
   width="42"/>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about adding ngFor AND ngIf but didn't do it that way.
Also it wont let me add the timer in ngOnInit.. I get an error on Timer saying ";" is expected..
ngOnInit() {
      this.loginService.loginText.subscribe(
        login => (this.login = login)
      )
      Timer(){
        setInterval(() => {
          this.count=this.count++
        }, 2000)
      }
    }

Comment: @Skimar That's probably because you are missing a semicolon.

`ngOnInit() { 
  this.loginService.loginText.subscribe(login => this.login = login);
  this.timer();
}

timer() { 
  setInterval(() => { 
    this.count++ 
  }, 2000); 
}`
This should technically work if you put it in the component